# Is it possible to share the same application context across the storm cluster?

Tags: java, spring, apache-storm

Storm serializes/deserializes class fields, but spring context is not serializable. Initializing the same in the prepare/out method of spout/bolt does not solve the problem.

What are the best practices around such cases where you may want the same spring context available across the cluster?

Comment: Putting aside spring for a second, what is it that you're trying to do? Can you explain the problem you're facing?

Comment: I need to establish connections with message queues and other such dependencies, but the number of connections one can establish is limited for one particular key, so the approach I took was to use singleton pattern and initialize them using spring.Apart from messaging queues there are other APIs required which are also supposed to be initialized once.

Answer (score 0):

First, the basics:

1. Workers - Run executors, *each worker has its own JVM*
2. Executors - Run tasks, each executor is distributed across various workers by storm
3. Tasks - Instances running your spout/bolt code

Think of each worker like a bucket where executors can be assigned.

You can control the number of instances of spouts/bolts when you first create and submit your topology:

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("0-spout", new MySpout(), spoutParallelism).setNumTasks(spoutTasks);
```

If you want only one spout for the entire cluster, you'd set both `spoutParallelism` and `spoutTasks` to 1.

This would allow you to control how many connections are being created to your message queue. The keys used to connect should be passed via storm config to the spout/bolt or loaded dynamically in `open` or `prepare`.

Comment: that's right, but lets say, in my cluster, the worker node running the executor goes down, one executor for the same spout is spawned on some other worker in the cluster.In this case the singleton is initialized again but there is a risk of previous such instance not being gracefully cleaned.

Comment: Yep. If the worker is dead and a new one spins up, why do you care the old one didn't shut down cleanly? You might need to look into using something like zookeeper for a distributed lock.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider [storm-jms](https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-jms) or [storm-kafka](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka), or some other similar things. Even if it's not exactly what you need, they can help you understand how to writter code in storm with good practice.